# Lipschitz continuity of $x\cdot\sin(1/x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I have to proof, that 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x \neq 0 \\ 
0 & x = 0 \\ 
\end{cases} $$ isn't Lipschitz continuous.

I have started with

$|f(x)-f(y)|$ and tried to get to $ \leq L \cdot | x-y| $ but without any success.

$|(1+\frac{y}{x-y})\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \frac{y}{x-y}\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{y})| \cdot |x-y|$ was best rearranging, but I don't know at this point how to simplify the $\sin$

I'm a mathematics student in first semester, so I am not allowed to use differential calculus.

Hints or solutions are welcome :)

Comment: _If_ you want to show that it is _not_ Lipschitz, then you should be happy that you do not succeed in showing the opposite. So, you want to show that there does not exist a constant $L$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L |x-y|$ for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So I should try to show the nagation of the statement? So that  $|f(x)−f(y)|> L|x−y|$?

Comment: You need to be careful about what precise statement it is that you have to prove.  A function is Lipschitz means that **there exists** an $L > 0$ such that **for any** $x,y \in \Bbb R$, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L|x - y|$.  The negation of the above statement is that **for every** $L > 0$, **there exists** a pair $x,y$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| > L|x - y|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to show that the ratio
$$
\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|}
$$
has no upper bound for $x,y \in \Bbb R$.  In particular, consider taking
$$
x = \frac{1}{2 \pi n + \pi/2}\\
y = \frac{1}{2 \pi n + 3\pi/2}
$$
for an arbitrary integer $n$.

Comment: Shouldn't it work for $ y = \frac{1}{2\pi n} $, too? If $sin(\frac{1}{y}) = 0$ it's a bit easier to calc. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Lu_kors yes, that will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

you know that the graph of $y=f(x)$ is contained between the lines $y=±x$ and that at every inverse odd multiples of $\pi/2$ it hits either of the boundaries. at these points $dx=O(1/n^2)$ and $dy=O(1/n)$ so the slope of the sedan line $dy/dx$ goes to infinity. you may want to use the MVT to see that there are points with these slopes on the graph at intermediate points.